# with appTheme actionbar disappears, why?

Tags: android, xml, android-actionbar, android-fragmentactivity

My main Activity extends **FragmentActivity** and if I use default app theme, **actionbar** disappears

**Style:**

```
<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="android:windowActionBar">true</item>
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
</style>
```

**with style in Manifest:**

[image]

**without android:theme="@style/AppTheme" in Android manifest:**

[image]

I tried to use **getActionBar().show()** in **FragmentActivity** but it simply returns null. Why this is happening and how can I turn on **actionbar** using style?

Comment: explain "style in manifest" ? Actionbar is controlled by Theme only.

Comment: FragmentActivity change to AppCompatActivity... also use  getSupportActionBar().show();

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of extending FragmentActivity, you need the main class to extend AppCompatActivity.

for more details see [That](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/creating.html)

Answer (score 0):

Try like this

```
<resources>
    <style name="CustomMaterialTheme" parent="CustomMaterialTheme.Base">
    </style>
    <style name="CustomMaterialTheme.Base" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
        <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="android:textColorPrimary">@color/textColorPrimary</item>
        <item name="android:windowBackground">@color/windowBackground</item>     
    </style>
</resources>
```

then use theme in manifest. Refer here: http://coderzpassion.com/android-working-with-material-design/